# Neutral item- Likert Scale

Tags: anova, data-transformation, mean, likert

I have already collected data using a Likert Scale 1: strongly disagree; 2: Disagree; 3: Neutral; 4: Agree; 5: Strongly Agree. I later understood that "neutral" option should have been avoided in questionnaire scales. But for now, how do I treat the data from the "neutral" option? I transformed the neutral data from 3 to 0, thinking that 3 would inflate my average of all my five items in the questionnaire. However, by transforming it from 3 to zero, and then averaging the five items, it is deflating my average value.

Do I treat this neutral as missing data, instead of zero? In that case, I will not count the items of the questionnaire that has neutral in my excel sheet. For example, 4+ 4+  0+  2+  0+  2+  4+  0+  5+  4+  0+  4+  4+  5=total/14= 2.71 Ave (zero is included); and by treating it as a missing data (excluding the zero), 4   +4      +2  +   2   +4      +5  +4  +   4   +4  + 5=total/10= Ave 3.8

Kindly advise.

Link of [previous posting]on Neutral option in Likert Type[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97525/neutral-option-on-likert-scale)

Comment: "I later understood that "neutral" option should have been avoided in questionnaire scales." Why do you think it should be avoided? Is it related to your analysis and area of research?

Comment: This is what I learned from the postings on stats.stackexchange.com; it may  be wrong, because I have personally filled many questionnaires that included the neutral option in the past. For now I need an answer about the best approach I should take to analyze my data. Thanks

Comment: I think this [link](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/likert.htm) provides some clarification about the meaning of likert scale, likert item, and likert-type item. You can see that one criterion is "Verbal labels are bivalent and symmetrical about a **neutral middle**." Could you share the CV posts you mentioned suggesting dropping neutral/middle category? Without a specific reason, it does not make sense to drop middle category.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97525/neutral-option-on-likert-scale

Comment: So how do we count the neutral option in such a scale? 1: strongly disagree; 2: Disagree; 3: Neutral; 4: Agree; 5: Strongly Agree.

Comment: Now I see, but again that question is not about dropping neutral category. That is one solution if you don't have separate options for neutral category and  "Don't know" (see [Lauren's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/97535/109647)). If your case is similar (without DK), then I think you can try Nick Stauner's suggestion.

Comment: Is "neutral" an appropriate label for middle category? Both answers to the question seem to imply it is inappropriate. In the link I posted it is considered appropriate. I guess it depends on item and open to discussion.

Comment: My question is if "neutral" is appropriate, do I have to include it into my averages or not (as per my original post above)? I need to carry out an ANOVA ultimately. Will including it or not including it make a difference?